# Having a hard time importing mySQL data to Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a .sql file that I want to import into django (or atleast the insert statements). I've been having a hard time trying to find out how to do this. There is about 50,000 entries in 4 insert statements in the form of:

```
INSERT INTO `tweets` VALUES (..........), (........), ... , (......).
```

I've been trying to understand fixtures and I'm not sure if its want I want, and if it is how to use it.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I've also got Django set up for a sqlite3 database because its been giving me a huge pain to change to mysql (perhaps because im using the windows linux subsystem?) so not sure if this makes a difference on inserting.

EDIT2: Models.py and the table I am trying to imitate (which is commented out):

```
class tweets(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    coord = models.CharField(max_length=40, default=None)
    datetime = models.CharField(max_length=20, default=None)

# CREATE TABLE `tweets` (
#   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
#   `tag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
#   `coord` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
#   `datetime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
#   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
# ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=57518 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
# /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

SQL script (which I've taken a lot out of from the original which someone optimized for PHP):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tweets`;
CREATE TABLE `tweets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `coord` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=57518 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tweets` VALUES (15579,'#MakeAmericaSmartAgain','-116.55183, 48.279752','21/03/2017 06:02:32'),(15580,'#fucksamus','-83.32891, 42.619824','21/03/2017 06:02:33'), .......... ();

INSERT INTO `tweets` VALUES (152349,'#morehashtags','-116.55183, 48.279752','21/03/2017 06:02:32'),(155280,'#andevenmore!!','-83.32891, 42.619824','21/03/2017 06:02:33'), .... , ();

..2 more insert statements then EOF
```

EDIT: I've tried using ./manage.py inspectdb tweets.sql , and this runs but gives me an error "unable to inspect table tweets.sql, the error was: Table tweets.sql doesnt exist". I also tried doing an sql dump through the sqlite command line, but it expects more input or doesn't work when I run commands for that as well..

Comment: Post models.py please

Comment: @pypypy Posted, sorry about that.

Comment: A few things: You probably want to add `null=True` to those field definitions. You may be better off using Django to create the tables (note default table names in Django will be different to what your SQL file will create) then using the sqlite3 command line client directly to import the sql dump. The other option is to do everything in the sql client and then use Django's `inspectdb` command to build your models file.  Note model names in Django are usually TitleCase and singular (`tweets` should be `Tweet`). This is not a use case for fixtures - fixtures are for JSON or yaml data.

Comment: Thanks. So I've been trying to use python manage.py dbshell to get into the sqlite terminal, then doing .read tweets.sql. This runs and shows all of the data in the SQL file, but doesn't actually add it anywhere and I can't seem to get around this.. any clue why? EDIT: I'll add (part of) the DB script in.